# Windows Phone with C++

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-phone, c++-cx

I want to make a Windows Phone app (version 7.5 and 8 preferably) in C++. I searched the net and came to know that for this purpose XAML is not supported and I will have to generate the UI from C++ itself, which I don't know how to. But in Windows Store apps, UI is generated by XAML and code-behind by C++/CX, which I find better. Is it possible to use C++/CX and XAML for the purpose or if you can give some resource on generating UI with C++?

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/98475feb-076f-434d-a5c8-24c8ccc4c9c0/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681687%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681693%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

I would encourage you to:

- Write your main project in C# (using XAML)
- Invoke (native, unmanaged) C++ modules as needed (for performance)

And please remember that XAML itself isn't necessarily portable between platforms.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know C# and do not wish to learn this at the moment

Comment: If you want to use XAML, then you need to program to .Net.  Your best bet is to learn at least a little C# (or VB.Net). IMHO...  And please do look at the use case table in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681693%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Note: C++ (ie. native code) development is not available for Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there are libraries for C# and VB.net for Windows Phone. XAML is very easy to use so you will not lose anything to write some. Also you have to think if your app will pass certification. So better speak with the support team of windows phone to get some help.